# how can i use certificate and private key with websocket in browser?

Tags: javascript, ssl, websocket

How to use certificate authentification for a websocket in the browser.

I did it with python, also i found many tutorials in doing it with nodejs, but is it possible in the browser with javascript too? I didn't find anything about that.

Here's my working python code(part of it to show what i mean)

```
import json
import websocket
import ssl

print("Start Websocket")
wsapp = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://localhost:8080",
                               on_open=on_open,
                               on_message=on_message,
                               on_error=on_error,
                               on_ping=on_ping)

wsapp.run_forever(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE, "certfile": "private.crt",
                          "keyfile": "private.key", "ssl_context.check_hostname": False})
wsapp.close()
```

Comment: If it works, then not the way you you suggest in your code using a private key file. Instead it may work that the web browser asks for a client certificate if the request requires so (in TLS handshake the server can request a client certificate and also provide a list of accepted root CAs). So from my perspective everything depends on the server configuration, it has to make a client certificate mandatory. If the web browser(s) can handle such a request on a WSS connection you will see if you test it.

Comment: then can the browser grant the web socket client to connect to another web socket server and optionally use different client SSL certificate (e.g. send data to LAN receipt printer agent via Web Socket, this agent forward documents to receipt printer) ?